# Android. ImageButton. How to rotate an image on a button. Not whole button

Tags: android, image, button, rotation, imagebutton

I have ***ImageButton*** with an image. I want to rotate **the ONLY image.** 
Not like this:
[rotating button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcVwv.gif)

That's what I have:

```html
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:src="@drawable/up"
    />
```

animation:

```html
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

java code:

```
public void clockwise(View view){
    ImageButton image = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),            R.anim.myanimation);<p>
    image.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

**Should I use AnimationDrawable or Matrix or any other approaches?**

Comment: is your code rotating the whole button?

Comment: yes, this is how it looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcVwv.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer, how to rotate the only image.
Thank you @Fondesa, I took your suggestion.

**1.** Amination file in **res/amin/ic_play_sound_animation.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="359"/>
</set>
```

**2.** A piece of **layout page** with two views(a button and image above):

```html
<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/frame"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_column="4"
      android:layout_row="3">
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_btn_play_sound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id_iv_play_sound_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_sound_1"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**3. Java code in Activity:**

```
    private ImageView playSoundIcon = (ImageView)view. findViewById (R.id.id_iv_play_sound_icon);

    private void runBtnAnimation() {
       playSoundIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_playing_sound_2);
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.ic_play_sound_animation);
        playSoundIcon.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

    private void stopBtnAnimation() {
        playSoundIcon.clearAnimation();
        playSoundIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_sound_1);
    }
```

**4.** you can watch GIF animation, how it looks like: 
[final animation on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5WYW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Separate your `Button` from your image using a `FrameLayout`. In this case you can set the click listener on the `Button`and apply the rotation only to the `ImageView`. This is easier and faster to accomplish but it's a workaround and the performance are better with the second choice because you haven't nested layouts:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/imageButton"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageButtonContent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. Use [`AnimationDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame). You can provide the list of drawables during the animation. I seriously recommend this one.

Comment: I tried with Animationdrawable, but it changed background and button become an image. here is a result:
http://imgur.com/a/Y7Xv8  as you can see, there is no gray button background.
So, I'm going to try your first approach.